# "Search bar" doesnt moving on right side even when i use ''d-flex justify-content-end"?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, positioning, searchbar

Can anyone tell me where i make mistake? i want to move my search bar at the end of right side.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#expandme">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="expandme">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#Home" class="nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
                <a href="#About" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a>
                <a href="#Contact" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <form class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <input class="form-control me-2 " type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Make a snippet here or a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring the form element outside of id:expandme, then try to use "d-flex justify-content-end"

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#expandme">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="expandme">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#Home" class="nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
                <a href="#About" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a>
                <a href="#Contact" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <input class="form-control mx-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```